# Setup a secure Peer to Peer connection over WIFI?

Tags: vnc, wifi, p2p

In my company we sometimes setup PC in hard to reach places. These PCs have WIFI USB dongles, and I want to control them from my laptop using VNC.

How do I setup a secure P2P connection over WIFI? All computers involved are running Win7 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to setup an "Ad Hoc" (client/client) wifi configuration versus an "Infrastructure" (client/access point) one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Windows 7 only supports using WEP encryption on Ad-Hoc wireless networks.  WEP encryption is pretty trivial to break - you should use something like [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/examples/vnc.html) to encrypt your VNC session if you actually want it to be secure.